# Concatenate a name in JavaScript if some of the items are missing

Tags: javascript

I need to combine the elements of a name and not include any extra white space. I may have data like

```
let FirstName = "John"
let MI = "G"
let LastName = "Jones"
let Suffix = "Jr."
```

And I would like to have let fullName = "John G Jones Jr."

but if I have

```
let FirstName = "John"
let MI = "" or null
let LastName = "Jones"
let Suffix = "" or null
```

I would like to have let fullName = "John Jones"
With no extra white spaces.

so

```
let fullName = FirstName + " " + MI + " " +LastName + " " + Suffix
```

Will not work.  Is there a way without a whole bunch of if statements?

This is all in a Vue.js page so I cannot use jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: "without a whole bunch of if statements?" --- you need just 2 checks, not "a whole bunch".

Comment: OK- without using if statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is put them in an array and filter the array to remove falsy values then join it using a space delimiter

```js
let FirstName = "John",
  MI = "",
  LastName = "Jones",
  Suffix = null,
  fullName = [FirstName, MI, LastName, Suffix].filter(v => v).join(' ');

console.log(fullName)
```